# How to perform a Regex replacement on one named capture group only?

Tags: java, c#, regex

If I have a varying regular expression that could look like any of the following patterns:

```
(.{2})(?<somedigit>\d+)(.{5})
(?<somedigit>\d+)(.{7})
(.{1})(?<somedigit>\d+)
```

and I want to replace the *somedigit* capture group with any number, and leave everything else untouched, how would I do that (say in C# or Java)?

For instance, say I have this text:

```
QB2-G456
```

and I use this regex:

```
(.{2})(?<somedigit>\d+)(.{5})
```

to match it, and say I want to replace the *somedigit* with 35, to get this final result:

```
QB35-G456
```

I know I can use this replacement text:

```
${1}35${2}
```

But the root of my question is that I do not know the format of my regular expression upfront.  So I cannot hard code the capture group references for the text I do not want to change, as there could be different variations.

Since multiple numbers may be present I cannot just replace \d+ as I do not know whether the numbers are in the beginning or end or middle and whether other numbers are present further-on in the text.

Ideally I was hoping for something like:

```
new Regex("(.{2})(?<somedigit>\d+)(.{5})").ReplaceCaptureGroup("QB2-G456", "somedigit", "35")
```

and have everything pass through unmodified except the *somedigit* capture group that is replaced.

I searched for similar issues and only found solutions to where the regex is fixed and known, as already explained above.

Comment: Why not convert the other groups into non-capturing (`(?:xxxx)` as opposed to `(xxxx)`)? Then you only have one thing to replace anyways?

Comment: Sure but how would I write that code?  I need to include the rest of the text to determine the position of the capturing group I want to replace, but if I do that, surely the whole match will be replaced?  Maybe a two liner example?

Comment: You should tag this with the language you're using.

Comment: I was hoping to find a solution that applies widely, maybe Java/ C# / Perl / etc.

Comment: If I understand @JohnBustos correctly, to write this generically:

`echo QB2-G456 | perl -ne 's/(.{2})\d+(.{5})/${1}35${2}/g; print'` which produces `QB35-G456`

using non capturing groups I would do: 

`echo QB2-G456 | perl -ne 's/(?:.{2})\d+(?:.{5})/35/g; print'` which produces `35`

but as you can see it only prints the replaced text, not the other text.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can do it in C#:

```
 var str1 = "QB2-G456";
 var rx1 = new Regex(@"(.{2})(?<somedigit>\d+)(.{5})");
 var res = rx1.Replace(str1, m => m.Value.Replace(m.Groups["somedigit"].Value, "35"));
// Result: QB35-G35456
```

This will replace all occurrences of the "somedigit" group contents inside the string (i.e. `QB2-G2456` will turn into `QB35-G35456`). To work around this, use a `Regex.Replace(input, regex, repl, numOfReplacements)` or this method:

```
public string ReplaceOnceAtIndex(string text, string search, string replace, int index)
{
    if (index < 0)
        return text;
    return text.Substring(0, index) + replace + text.Substring(index + search.Length);
}
// ... And thenin the caller ...
var res2 = rx1.Replace(str1, m => 
ReplaceOnceAtIndex(m.Value, m.Groups["somedigit"].Value, "35", m.Groups["somedigit"].Index));
// Result: QB35-G2456
```